# Proof of how many ways to turn one value into another

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was recently involved in a conversation where somebody wanted to know if it was possible to determine the next number in a sequence from the numbers that were provided. The sequence initially had 3 elements, and was later expanded to 4. The issue was that the sequence was created by starting with an arbitrary value and then alternating between subtracting 1 and multiplying by 3. When there were 3 elements in the sequence, there was only one example of each type of operation. When it was expanded to 4 elements, there were two examples of subtracting 1, but there was still only one example of multiplying by 3. Because of this, various people pointed out that it is impossible to determine the exact equation used to turn one specific value into another from only one example. In this case it was turning 5 into 15, which could be done by multiplying by 3, adding 10, etc.. I want to say that there is an infinite number of ways to do this, but I'm not sure whether that's actually correct.

Given the constants *a* and *b*, is there a proof that either establishes either a limit to the number of ways you can turn *a* into *b*? Is there a proof shows that there are ways you can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are infinitely many ways os doing that:

- Take $a$ and then add $b-a$ to it; you will get $b$.
- Take $a$ again and then add $2b-a$ to it. You will get $2b$. Then, divide it by $2$, and you will get $b$.
- Take $a$ again and then add $3b-a$ to it. You will get $3b$. Then, divide it by $3$, and you will get $b$.
- And so on…

Of course, I am **not** saying that there are no more ways.

Comment: like subtracting $a-b$ ...